# How to implement ASP.NET Core MVC AJAX requests using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working in asp.net webforms and jquery ajax since many years and now want to implement a project in asp.ner core using same front end technology jQuery Ajax.

Comment: For the general approach you could have a look at the documentation, i.e. [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1)), and [Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which you would need to adapt to use `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery implementation is same across multiple platforms. You can use similar code.

Example of jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/controller/Action'
          data: { parameter1 : 'value', parameter2 : 'value' },
          success: function (response) {
                       // code on successful completion
                   }
          error: function (response) {
                     // code on failure
                 }
});
```

Comment: This should be the top, accepted answer. It's clear, concise and doesn't have any erroneous code.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply inline `data-ajax-*` attributes as below:

Include jquery libraries:

```html
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive@3.2.6/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

Apply data-ajax attributes to anchor element:

```html
<!-- ajax content will load inside this div -->
<div id="data-div"></div>

<a href="#" 
    data-ajax="true" 
    data-ajax-mode="replace" 
    data-ajax-update="#data-div" 
    data-ajax-loading="#loading"
    data-ajax-url="@Url.Page("Index", "ServerDate")">Run Ajax Request</a>

<!-- spinning loading indicator -->
<span id="loading" style="display:none;"> <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
```

and the backend method:

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet() { }

    public ContentResult OnGetServerDate()
    {
        return Content($"{DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

Same attributes can be applied to the forms as well.

See demos here: http://demo.ziyad.info/en/AjaxRequest